# How to change "Default Value Store View in 1.9.2?

Tags: magento-1.9, language

I´m getting crazy, I´m trying to install a new language to my shop. I´m working with Magento 1.9.2, them, I select germain.

After get the URL to install in Magento Connect, I install my new extension, everything looks like good.

[image]

After that, I get a `Succesfully Clean Cache`, etc... good.

But, now I want my shop in this language, I go to `Manage Storage > Main Website Store`:

[image]

I want to change the 4th option and set "`Germain`" or something, but I can´t change.

I am forgetting something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System>Config>General>Locale

Change your Current Configuration Scope on the left hand side as desired.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, its works now. But I would like to know something. Why I cant change the language in my mode? I mean, if I have a shop in China it will show in spanish Am I wrong?

Comment: If you want to have different language versions of your site you can create a new store view so for example English and set its locale to English gb. This would then give your user the option to change language of your store. You can add as many language store fronts as you need as long as you have the language packs to do so. Worth giving a read https://www.ubertheme.com/docs/setup-multiple-languages-currencies/

Comment: After read your documentation, I understand my mistake, thanks, I had a mess.  Thanks =).